# Hilbert Spaces of Random Variables

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Recently, I found an interesting website on spaces of random variables:

> [http://www.randomservices.org/](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Spaces.html)

Can you recommend me some resources on the topics enclosed in this link?

Comment: it took all 6908 of your rep to make me feel comfortable clicking that

Comment: @Timkinsella: I upvoted the question just to make that comment out of date :-)